# Log visitors ip address in Dart

Tags: dart

How can I log my site visitors ip address in Dart?

Is there something similar to  `Request.UserHostAddress` in Asp.net for Dart?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure can! Check out [HttpRequest.connectionInfo](https://api.dartlang.org/dart_io/HttpRequest.connectionInfo) and the [HttpConnectionInfo class](https://api.dartlang.org/dart_io/HttpConnectionInfo)

Eg: `request.connectionInfo.remoteAddress`